# window.scroll triggers at the start of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the opacity value of a div block on scroll.

```
     $(window).scroll(function(e) {
            var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            opacityVal = (s / 200.0);
            $('.blur').css('opacity', opacityVal);
     });
```

If the div block is somewhere in the middle of the page.By the time I reach the div block the opacity value changes . How do I start $(window).scroll() to work when I reach the div block?

Comment: Precise "when I reach the div block" ! When the bottom of the window is on the top of the div ? When the div becomes to be visible ? ... Does a part of the div can be visible at the beggining ?

Comment: Sorry for the being unclear..I mean to say when the div becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

Include the div element scrollTop and window height in your calculations.  This will begin your opacity animations when the div is at the bottom of the visible window area.  I've also added a 'clamp' function to keep it in 0-1 range.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop() - $('.blur').scrollTop() - $(window).height(),
        opacityVal = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, s/400));
    $('.blur').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/AGcYH/